# how to create a 1 second delay Arduino

Tags: arduino, delay, no-op

Hi i'm new to Arduino and i'm trying to create a 1 second delay but i don't know how i can generate a code that completes the delay_ms function
I've tried to work it out but doesn't seem to get any better
Thank you
    void setup() 
    {

```
word millisecs;   
Serial.begin(9600); 
}   
void setup() asm volatile(
"          ldi r16,0x3F    ; r16 = 00111111\n"
"          out 4,r16       ; set pins 8-13 as outputs in DDRB\n"
::: "r16");
millisecs = 1000;            // 1s blink delay
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() 
{
long starttime = millis();        // make a note of the start time

asm volatile(
// jump to "blink" - ie jump around the delay_ms subroutine
"            rjmp  blink%=        ; relative jump to 'blink' \n"
  "          ldi r16,0x3F    ; r16 = 00111111\n"
"          out 4,r16       ; set pins 8-13 as outputs in DDRB\n"
::: "r16");

 registers used:
 r31 - millisecond count (lo byte)
 r30 - millisecond count (hi byte)
 r17 - 100 microsecond count
 r16 - 1 microsecond count
Overall delay (ms) = r30:r31 * r17 * r16
---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
"delay_ms%=:    nop                 ; code to replace  nop  \n"
"delay_100us%=: nop                 ; code to replace  nop  \n"
"delay_1us%=:   nop                 ; code to replace nop  \n"
"               sbiw r30,1          ; decrement ms count (r31:r30)\n"
"               brne delay_ms%=     ; loop to delay_ms while > 0  \n"
"               ret                 ; return from subroutine      \n"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in to do this

```
http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/delay
```

you just give it the number of ms to delay. So for one second

```
delay(1000)
```

Comment: yeah but i want to complete it without using the built in i need to figure out how to complete delay_ms% delay_100us% and delay_1us% functions Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are working way too hard for something so simple. See [BlinkWithoutDelay](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) (code below). That code is also part of the Arduino examples which get installed when you install the Arduino IDE. Lots of good learning examples in there. (Oh - the code uses a `long` for the var `previousMillis`. That is an error (imo). It would be better to use an `unsigned long`.)

You also have the option of using [Timer interrupts](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1) but for a simple second delay (esp. if you don't have much experience), I would suggest the method above and do it all in code that is simple to understand.

```
/* Blink without Delay

 Turns on and off a light emitting diode(LED) connected to a digital  
 pin, without using the delay() function.  This means that other code
 can run at the same time without being interrupted by the LED code.

 The circuit:
 * LED attached from pin 13 to ground.
 * Note: on most Arduinos, there is already an LED on the board
 that's attached to pin 13, so no hardware is needed for this example.


 created 2005
 by David A. Mellis
 modified 8 Feb 2010
 by Paul Stoffregen

 This example code is in the public domain.


 http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay
 */

// constants won't change. Used here to
// set pin numbers:
const int ledPin =  13;      // the number of the LED pin

// Variables will change:
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED
long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated

// the follow variables is a long because the time, measured in miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
long interval = 1000;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

void setup() {
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);      
}

void loop()
{
  // here is where you'd put code that needs to be running all the time.

  // check to see if it's time to blink the LED; that is, if the
  // difference between the current time and last time you blinked
  // the LED is bigger than the interval at which you want to
  // blink the LED.
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;  

    // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
    if (ledState == LOW)
      ledState = HIGH;
    else
      ledState = LOW;

    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes but i want to write the blink function in assembly language i already know how to use the timer Thank you

Comment: @user3669884 - well then why didn't you SAY that in your question rather than wasting our time by not providing sufficient information.